# Devexpress ASPxGridViewExporter not working

Tags: devexpress

I have the following code but when I press the export button all I get is a download popup for the asp.net page, this case default.aspx

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnPdfExport" runat="server" Text="Export to PDF" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
                OnClick="btnPdfExport_Click" />
```

And the grid and exporter

```
 <dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExport" GridViewID="grid" runat="server">
</dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server"
    CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Black/{0}/styles.css" OnAutoFilterCellEditorCreate="grid_AutoFilterCellEditorCreate"                
    OnAutoFilterCellEditorInitialize="grid_AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize" KeyFieldName="ProductCode" OnProcessColumnAutoFilter="grid_ProcessColumnAutoFilter" 
    CssPostfix="Office2010Black" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Size="Small">
```

The code behind

```
protected void btnPdfExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridExport.Landscape = true;
        gridExport.WritePdfToResponse("view");
    }
```

The strange thing is that this exact code works perfectly on another page, when I press the button I get view.pdf, any ideas

James

Comment: what browser are you using? have you tried to rename your the exported file default.aspx to something like default.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code.It is working.There is no any error or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPdfExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```